# Has anyone used the Cyton Arm With ROS?

Tags: ros, urdf, openrave, manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody used the Cyton Arm (http://www.robai.com/) with ros? I'm interested in things such as a URDF description, and anything required to get it working with OpenRAVE.

I see that the servos in it can be controlled by the ax12_controller_core ros node. (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ax12_controller_core)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10241/has-anyone-used-the-cyton-arm-with-ros?/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wheeler.ruml](https://answers.ros.org/users/4494/wheeler.ruml/) on 2013-03-21**:
I have a cyton arm and would like to use it with ROS, so I guess I have this same question.  I would prefer something as high-level as possible (eg, how to use with arm_navigation or moveit).  Thanks!

**Comment by [Okke](https://answers.ros.org/users/7721/okke/) on 2013-10-13**:
Same here, I am looking for a gazebo model/controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ax12_controller_core package is deprecated and will be removed as soon as ETurtle is released. I suggest you use the recently released [dynamixel_motor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_motor) stack instead. It's pretty much the same code cleaned up and packaged into a single stack.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2